# Hold Em poker How minimum raise changes

Tags: rules

I am having difficulties at understanding minimum raise. From other answers I understand that minimum raise is equal to last bet. I do not understand if minimum raise changes from a round to the other. I will try to give an example in a No Limit scenario.

Example 1:
Preeflop
Player A -> small blind 100
Player B -> big blind 200
Player C -> raise 600
At this point is minimum raise 400?
After round over, does minimum raise doubles, remains as it is or resets to big blind?

Comment: Sorry, I did not come across it.

Comment: Not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum raise (or bet) starts at the same amount each betting round. In your example, the minimum raise (bet) would become 200 when the next betting round begins.